# DIV is generating 2 times on checkout page (WOO COMMERCE)?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

The problem starts when user clicks on shipping details checkbox. The div with class `order-detail-summary-outer` automatically generates when user checks the box.On the checkout page when user checkbox for the shipping details the order summary doubles. I have done many modifications in the in past. So i think i made mistake.On clicking shipping information checkbox. the order summary becomes double. only subtotal, shipping and total.

[image]
[image]

I am providing **review-order.php** file code below

```
<?php
/**
 * Review order table
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.8.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
?>
<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-total"><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents' );

        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                ?>
                <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                    <td class="product-name">
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;'; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times;&nbsp;%s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '</strong>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                        <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="product-total">
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }

        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents' );
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="order-detail-summary-outer">

        <div class="cart-subtotal">
            <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
            <div class="order-detail-summary-item"><?php wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html(); ?></div>
        </div>

        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
            <div class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                <h2><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></h2>
                <div class="order-detail-summary-item"><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
<h2>Shipping</h2>
        <?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>

            <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
            <div class="fee">
                <h2><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></h2>
                <div class="order-detail-summary-item"><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( wc_tax_enabled() && ! WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) : ?>
            <?php if ( 'itemized' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_total_display' ) ) : ?>
                <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_tax_totals() as $code => $tax ) : // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.OverrideProhibited ?>
                    <div class="tax-rate tax-rate-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                        <h2><?php echo esc_html( $tax->label ); ?></h2>
                        <div class="order-detail-summary-item"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $tax->formatted_amount ); ?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <div class="tax-total">
                    <h2><?php echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); ?></h2>
                    <div class="order-detail-summary-item"><?php wc_cart_totals_taxes_total_html(); ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total' ); ?>

        <div class="order-total">
            <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
            <div class="order-detail-summary-item"><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></div>
        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total' ); ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the class "woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table" from table tag and wrap the whole mark up inside a new div like:

```
<div class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table"> 
    // your all mark up...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This matter could come from many things, a mistake in sql query, an javascript that duplicate div, ...

If it's from php side, i don't know WOOCommerce but can you apply \array_unique() method on your loop to remove duplicates (e.g code below as a workaround).

```
<?php foreach ( \array_unique(WC()->cart->get_coupons()) as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

PS : But i'm sure it's an mistake on javascript side.

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance. It looks to be how you modified the existing HTML structure. WooCommerce uses a lot of ajax calls to update that information (cart totals, checkout totals). If you have modified that structure and it doesn't know where to send it back/replace it, it will inject a new section.

As LsKIT stated, its a JS issue but more so because of the modified HTML.